# Jquery cookie plugin - how to set cookie for show/open element

Tags: jquery, cookies

When I navigate away from page to another one I need to remember whitch block is open 
This is colapsible mavigation menu.The div 'block' content has links inside.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!-- 

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.acc_container').hide(); 
    $('.acc_trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show(); 

    $('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { 
            $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().hide(); 
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().show();
        }
        return false; 
    });
    });

    //--><!]]>
    </script>


<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Messages</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
          <div class="block">content1    </div>
        </div>
    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Categories</a></h2>
        <div class="acc_container">
          <div class="block">content2    </div>
        </div>
.....
<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Clients</a></h2>
        <div class="acc_container">
          <div class="block">content10   </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why Cookie ? You can use [data() function](http://api.jquery.com/data)

Comment: just a quick tutorial: [H E R E!](http://roko.x10.mx/cookie/) (use the google translator ;) ) look at the DEMO3! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.acc_container').hide(); 
    $('.acc_trigger')
      .eq( $.cookie('activeTrigger'))//<!-- read index from cookie
        .addClass('active').next().show(); 

    $('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
       $.cookie('activeTrigger',$('.acc_trigger').index(this));//<!-- set the cookie
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { 
            $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().hide(); 
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().show();
        }
        return false; 
    });
    });
```

It stores onclick the index of the clicked item inside `$('.acc_trigger')` to a cookie , later it uses this index to select this item via `$().eq()`